# Is there a way to go through components faster?

Tags: delphi, components

I am using this code. in D2007.

```
FOR I := 0 to ComponentCount -1 do Begin
    if Components[I] IS TPanel then
        TPanel(Components[I]).Color := clWhite;
End;
```

I just need those with the same Parent and/or of the same type.

How Is it possible ?

Thanks

Oh!!! I am sorry ...

So I need to be able to iterate trough my forms components as fast as possible, Ok?

The sample above goes trough to much components. correct ?

I can do `Parent.ComponentCount`, but this only solve on small part.

Is there a way to only get Some components, like TPanels, or Tlabels what ever necessary ?

Is this clearer guys ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating over the form's `Components[]` property and using the `is` operator does not sound like it would be a performance bottleneck. I suppose if your form has huge numbers of components then the performance could be an issue. But that would be a rather unusual scenario.

Perhaps it would be better to use the parent/child relationship rather than the lifetime relationship. That is use the `Controls[]` or `WinControls[]` properties.

However, if performance really is an issue then arrange that you only iterate once. Store the results of that iteration in a container, e.g. a dynamic array or a list, and use that container subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and suggest that when you create your panels and populate each one with controls, build a `TList<TControl>` (or another base class that may be more appropriate, like WinControl or TComponent) and add the controls to it that you want to deal with later. Then save the reference to that list in the panel's `.Tag` property.

That way each list will have EXACTLY the components on it that you want to address, and you won't have to waste any code sifting through unwanted components.

I could suggest a way to deal with it easily using a non-Delphi library, but the folks here don't believe that sort of thing is of service to SO's users, so you'll have to go elsewhere for such suggestions.